# Running the search function in Rails will output all values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

## What I want to come true

Implementing a search function in Rails. I've written the code, but the search function doesn't work. What should I do?
I want to implement it without using gem this time.

## Code

**controller**

```rb
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

・・・ 

  def search
    @movies = Movie.search(params[:search])
  end

・・・
end
```

**model**

```rb
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
    def self.search(search)
        if search
            Movie.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
        else
            Movie.all
        end
    end
end
```

**View**
index and search

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'movies', media: 'all'%>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="search">
    <%= form_with url: search_path, method: 'get' do |form|%>
        <%= form.text_field :keyword, value: @keyword %>
        <%= form.submit "Search" %>
    <% end %>

    <div>
    </div>
</div>

    <div class="movies_item">
    <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
        <div class="movies_data">
            <%=image_tag movie.image_url %> 
            <p><%= movie.name %> </p>   
            <p>Details</p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Search results

```rb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'movies', media: 'all'%>
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="search">
    <%= form_with url: search_path, method: 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search%>
        <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>
</div>

    <% @movies.each do |movie| %>
            <div class="movies_data">
            <%= image_tag movie.image_url %> 
            <p><%= movie.name %> </p>   
            <p> Details </p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

**routes**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :admin do
    resources :movies
    get 'search', to: 'movies#search'
  end
end
```

## Error

No error will be generated, but all the DB data will be output.

## What I've tried.

・I removed `Movie.all` in model to check the behavior, but all values were output.

・Using rails c, `where(name: "search_name")` worked.

・However, if `Movie.where(['name LIKE ? , "%search_name%"])` did not get the value. (The SQL search method is wrong. Or I don't know if the search function can't be executed because this can't be retrieved)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `:keyword, value: @keyword` to `:search` in View index and search, and it displays correctly. `:search`

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass two separate parameters, not an array:

```
# correct
Movie.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

```
# wrong
Movie.where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed ``[ ]``, but the search results still show all values.

Comment: @Kekaji what is the URL you get after submitting the form?

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't have enough information as it is, I'm trying to make it searchable from index. I added the code as ``index and search`` to the question text.